Our SES SMTP credentials are leaked periodically
We are using SES SMTP with cPanel webmail (Exim) and PHP to send emails. This issue happened today and last week. Currently, We have the credentials in 2 places:
1- Exim configuration.
2- PHP files.
Someone managed to got these credentials today and sent thouthands of spam emails as our main domain email.
Server Details:
Server: EC2 instance
Operating system: Rocky 9
CPanel: 120.0 (build 5)
Exim: 4.97.1-1.cp118~el9

Network groups:
Port       Source
20         0.0.0.0/0
21         0.0.0.0/0
22         0.0.0.0/0
25         0.0.0.0/0
26         0.0.0.0/0
53         0.0.0.0/0
80         0.0.0.0/0
443        0.0.0.0/0
465        0.0.0.0/0
579        0.0.0.0/0
587        0.0.0.0/0
588        0.0.0.0/0
783        0.0.0.0/0
993        0.0.0.0/0
995        0.0.0.0/0
2077       0.0.0.0/0
2078       0.0.0.0/0
2080       0.0.0.0/0
2082       0.0.0.0/0
2083       0.0.0.0/0
2086       0.0.0.0/0
2087       0.0.0.0/0
2089       0.0.0.0/0
2095       0.0.0.0/0
2096       0.0.0.0/0
3306       0.0.0.0/0

Here is one of the spam email headers:
Received: from ****.****.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:400:19f::19)
 by ****.***.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:400:34::9) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7611.19; Wed, 22 May
 2024 12:20:41 +0000
Received: from ***.***.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
 (2603:10a6:400:19f:cafe::3f) by ****.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10a6:400:19f::19) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.7587.36 via Frontend
 Transport; Wed, 22 May 2024 12:20:41 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 54.240.48.44)
 smtp.mailfrom=amazonses.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=domain.com;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=domain.com;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of amazonses.com designates
 54.240.48.44 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=54.240.48.44; helo=a48-44.smtp-out.amazonses.com; pr=C
Received: from a48-44.smtp-out.amazonses.com (54.240.48.44) by
 ***.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.167.240.5) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.7611.14 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 22 May 2024 12:20:40 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=tvrgujtggesmotqmrstlakcrqpx6xeug; d=domain.com; t=****;
    h=MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID;
    bh=X/Qk8JBK/jkWh4pr1nW3cFWfK30/ChakGMwXRzRjBtI=;
    b=IJ7TBpCNP3AxSdY4Vvz1tqkFdZDLQYpgOl8PuYFZIcQLG+llDXoHkNOb+qMLyTT5
    Hi3q4Sl/9FoD2yH+KhK+XdES5hHYuPX0v/c3AId635bQyDXOa36eXjAwzS8QA/hPMe9
    gq3c5SUlm5ZqwG5I4nvQXDcgPFzOcOhApchIFLibJ0QtPu11BS8MpqEtMSpUUYzLZjc
    +DNDbLhwu1dmTdR/CCS61PyAq2IXGhIjvW51ZZ5dflT9apOC/WxeuJl/+RSTlEfouaW
    s2VcU19GYtxzCjHy/jGrhlr05vsewJs23kIQQEov8XfuQDiwx6OThhn5OCQyzNOrWLk
    LpDR3A4MTw==
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=ug7nbtf4gccmlpwj322ax3p6ow6yfsug; d=amazonses.com; t=1716380439;
    h=MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID:Feedback-ID;
    bh=X/Qk8JBK/jkWh4pr1nW3cFWfK30/ChakGMwXRzRjBtI=;
    b=o9RfQg2ZCvBH3eTDwYkpb3sJ5GX8Ni9iYVoWy5EyBuFgCwUWk15vecwG3OIDORFb
    KSPOGcpFcfDIh77zioTpilDThZWocMhGKFl3f/uCU4tM81x8e+/pcdnPZrPGTU6LFvV
    bXjpdm7FaOlRk1XYy+9GpRyXNXnaX7YajpszRtz0=
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Newsletter <info@domain.com>
To: receiver@***.info
Date: Wed, 22 May 2024 12:20:39 +0000
Subject: Expand Your Horizons with OP
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-ID: <******0@email.amazonses.com>
Feedback-ID: ::****=:AmazonSES
X-SES-Outgoing: 2024.05.22-54.240.48.44
Return-Path:
    *****@amazonses.com
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 70c07d08-b16b-4061-ac7c-ded97b37fe4a:0
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: CW2PEPF000056BA:EE_|CWXP123MB3270:EE_
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 7612e453-7187-4729-1ab9-08dc7a599867


Check your Exim/php/www logs. You need to figure out how the email is being sent. Exim could be acting as an open relay, or some php has a code injection vuln, or worst case youve actually been hacked/rooted.  You should review your firewall asap and follow principal of least privilege (port 25 rings alarm bells - unencrypted SMTP is a favourite of spammers). Do some research on these points and consider posting on superuser.com/serverfault.com as appropriate. Voting to close as off topic. Good luck!
